# understanding link_to syntax and hash params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The syntax for this line from chapter 6 of the Agile confuses me as does the documentation. Im having a lot of trouble understanding what is going on when hashes are used as parameters.

The line is this:

```
link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

The [shortened man page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is this:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

> Creates a link tag of the given name using a URL created by the set
>   of options.  See the valid options in the documentation for url_for.
>
> **Options**
>
> • :data - This option can be used to add custom data attributes.
>
> • method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing
>   using the HTTP verb specified.
>
> **Data attributes**
>
> • confirm: 'question?' - This will allow the unobtrusive JavaScript driver to prompt with the question specified (in this case, the resulting text would be question?.

In this case it looks like I am passing 1 parameter (name = 'Destroy') and one hash for options. There is no HTML options hash or code block. None of the url_for options are specified.

Ive had trouble understanding the man page. The "Options" section describes some (but not all) allowable values for the options hash. One parameter in the options hash is :data and the "Data Attributes" section describes options for that hash. While it looks like they are describing equal things, the Data attributes are actually nested inside the Options hash.

If I got that correct then it looks like the Options hash includes a second hash, called :data, which is where I pass the confirm: value.

I could re-write the line with more parens to make explicit hashes like so:

```
link_to ('Destroy', { product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } })
```

Assuming I got all that right, I dont understand the first element of the options hash, **product**.

Doesnt a hash element require a hash key? It looks like a model class is just thrown in there... I thought it was a parameter but that seems wrong.

am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `{ product, method: :delete` is invalid syntax. You can't have an element in a hash which is only a value (ie, `product`). Hashes have key/value pairs.

You've guessed wrong because you're relying on the method signature, but there is no type-checking of arguments in Ruby, so the function can "rewrite" its arguments however it wants.

The documentation tells you that `link_to` has *many* signatures:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
  # posts_path

link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
  # url_options, except :method, is passed to url_for

link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

In your case, you're using the second version, with `(body, url_options, html_options)`.

The line breaks down like this:

- `'Destroy',` - `body`: The label that will appear on the button
- `product,` - `url_options`: The model being linked to. It will be passed to `url_for`, which will examine the model's class's name to determine the name of the URL helper method to invoke; based on your variable name, it will probably be `product_path(product)`
- `method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` - `html_options`: The options hash

If you wanted to write it with more punctuation and whitespace, it would look like this:

```
link_to(
  'Destroy',
  product,
  {
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This explanation was very helpful. I find these signatures pretty confusing and clearly did not guess that the second option was the right signature.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter "options" does not have to be a Hash. It can be a String.

> It's also possible to pass a String instead of an options hash, which generates a link tag that uses the value of the String as the href for the link.

In your case, I think "product" should be something like "product_path".

```
link_to 'Destroy', product_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

'Destroy' is your first parameter, product_path is your second parameter and the rest if the third parameter.